# Run BitTorrent Sync in API mode

Tags: api, bittorrent, bittorrent-sync

I want to use the API of BitTorrent Sync. For this I first have to run it in API mode.
I was checking the "Enabling the API" section in the following link:
http://www.bittorrent.com/sync/developers/api

But I am unable to run it.
Can anybody please share some experience with it. I am new to it.

Here is what I execute in command prompt:-

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\BitTorrent Sync>btsync.exe /config D:\config.api
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my mistake. This is the right way to run it:

```
BTSync.exe /config D:\config.api
```

The problem was with the config file. Here is the way it should be:

```
{  
    // path to folder where Sync will store its internal data,  
    // folder must exist on disk  
    "storage_path" : "c://Users/Folder1/btsync",  
    // run Sync in GUI-less mode  
    "use_gui" : true,    
    "webui" : {  
        // IP address and port to access HTTP API  
        "listen" : "0.0.0.0:9090",  
        // login and password for HTTP basic authentication  
        // authentication is optional, but it's recommended to use some  
        // secret values unique for each Sync installation  
        "login" : "api",  
        "password" : "secret",  
        // replace xxx with API key received from BitTorrent  
        "api_key" : "xxx"  
    }  
}
```

Comment: How to do it on MAC ? Can You please help me?

Comment: I tried above link but it is showing "unrecognized option `--config'" Here is command I am using on Terminal- ["open BTSync.dmg --config /User/Developer/Desktop/config.api"] I also tried this- ['sudo BTSync.dmg --config /User/Developer/Desktop/config.api"] it shows BTSync.dmg command not found. Where I am wrong ?? Please help